# Printing date with custom format

Tags: entities, datetime

I want to **print "event_info_date" Date (Unix timestamp) field with custom format** in **node.tpl.php**.

I'm using this code:

```
<?php print date("Y/m/d h:i:s", $node->event_info_date['und'][0]['value']); ?>
```

And it prints: **1970/01/01 01:00:00**, but it isn't value from my field.

I've also tried this:

```
<?php print format_date($node->event_info_date['und'][0]['value'], 'custom', 'Y/m/d h:i:s'); ?>
```

But it doesn't print anything. **Any ideas?**

Comment: So, based on what I see here, it's not the date() function, but the value in the second argument. It must not be returning a valid date because it's printing essentially the first date. Any more code to assist? Are you doing this in a hook? Also, pedantically, I recommend LANGUAGE_NONE rather than 'und'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**print date("Y/m/d h:i:s", strtotime($node->event_info_date['und'][0]['value']));**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This code is printing this: **1970/01/01 01:00:00**, while the value of the field is: **2015/09/30 00:56:00**

Comment: can you send me the exact value you are getting in this: "$node->event_info_date['und'][0]['value']".
you can do this by :
drupal_set_message($node->event_info_date['und'][0]['value']); or direct print.

Comment: One more thing if you're not getting any value in this that means either you array structure is not proper, so try this one to get the structure:

drupal_set_message(print_r($node->event_info_date,1));